# How to prevent Docker Desktop from starting after log in on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker on Windows 10 version 1809.
Everything work great except that Docker starts after every reboot automatically although I have unchecked 'Start Docker when you log in' in settings.

Is there a registry setting that I can use instead or something? I am using Docker only for testing purpose and don't want to waste to much RAM.

- Docker Desktop version:

[image: Docker_Desktop_version]

- Docker Desktop general settings:

[image: Docker_Desktop_general_settings]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried disabling it in task manager?

1. Open task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, then click Task Manager)
2. In bottom left corner, click "More details"
3. In the top tabs, go to Startup.
4. Look and see if Docker is located in here, and disable it if it is.
5. That should be all, I guess restart to see if it still starts up or not.

Comment: That worked. So simple but yet powerfull :-) Thanks!

Comment: Voted up and helpful, thanks, but this is a workaround: the question why Docker Desktop is not respecting the _Start Docker when you log in_ option is still unanswered

Comment: It was disabled for me, but still had a VM running that I could see in the Hyper-V-Manager. I ended up shutting down the VM there followed by manually disabling the Docker Desktop Service

Comment: It still starts up even when it's disabled in the startup programs list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have docker desktop configured to not start with windows, and you have disabled it in the startup programs (via task manager or windows settings) and you still see DockerDesktop.exe in task manager or in the systray (like the screenshot below), go to Services and find the "Docker Desktop Service" (also in the picture below) and Stop it and set its startup to Manual or Disabled and click Apply or OK.
[image]